# WooCommerce login area redirect to default Wordpress login form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-accounts, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce's "My Account" page shows a register/login form if the user isn't logged in, but I'm trying to use the default Wordpress login/register page (wp-login.php) instead.

How can I make "/my-account" redirect to "wp-login.php" if the user isn't logged in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally the Woocommerce "customer" user role, can't access to the admin  of wordpress. But you can use a function hocked in **`woocommerce_before_customer_login_form`** hook with a mixed condition to redirect user to classic wordpress login area, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'redirect_customer_login_access');
function redirect_customer_login_access() {

    // Here the conditions (woocommerce my account pages and unlogged user)
    if( is_account_page() && !is_user_logged_in()){

        // Define here the redirection after login (optional)
        $redirection_after = site_url( '/shop/' );

        // Redirecting to Wordpress login area
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $redirection_after ) );

        // always use exit after wp_redirect() function.
        exit; 
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).

**This code is tested and works.**